# Count number of posts of current month

Tags: posts, get-posts, count

I am trying to echo the number of posts for the current month from all categories but it isnt working.

```
<?php
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');
$countposts = get_posts('post_type=post&year=' . $year . '&monthnum=' . $month . '&cat=3');
echo 'New posts '  . count($countposts);
?>
```

category 3 is a parent category and has many sub categories. No matter what I do, it returns the value 5. I have published 30 posts for this month to test it but it doesnt count them. :(

What Im I doing wrong?

**Update** I have tried the following query and returns the same outpout

```
    <?php
wp_reset_postdata();
$current_year = date('Y');
$current_month = date('m');
$args = array(
    'cat'      => 3,
    'year'     => $current_year,
    'monthnum' => $current_month,
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'post_type'       => 'post'
);
$number_posts = get_posts( $args );
echo 'New posts '  . count($number_posts);
?>
```

Comment: Try using this : $month = date('n');

Answer (score 2):

This is because the paramenter `posts_per_page` of the `get_posts()` function [defaults to 5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts). Set it to -1 in your `$args`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `get_posts` function to count posts.

It will select these posts and it can be a lot of data that you will transfer/read from database and you won't use.

The other problem is that `get_posts` is very complex function. Just take a look at `get_posts` implementation in `wp-includes/query.php` file and check how many operations it does. So it's not very efficient solution for counting posts.

So instead I would use custom SQL query. It will be much more efficient. You can use this function:

```
function my_count_posts_from_month($year, $month) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT count(ID) FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' AND YEAR(post_date)=%d AND MONTH(post_date)=%d";    

    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $query, $year, $month ));
}
```

Comment: Note that with `'fields' => 'ids'` it is pretty light on SQL and data. It is _much_ easier to deal with query API in the long run than raw SQL.

Comment: @Rarst and yet, if there will be 100k posts, then you'll have to SELECT 100k IDs instead of getting only the count from DB. But I totally agree that using get_posts is easier to deal with later on.

Comment: @Rarst  Can you elaborate on this approach?